# awk syntax for getting part of a matched regex

Tags: regex, perl, awk, match

Am sure this is easy, so apologies. In Perl I might do something like

```
my $str = "foo=23";
$str ~= m/foo=([0-9]+)/
print "foo value is " . $1
```

ie use parentheses in the regex to be able to refer to part of the match later as $1, $2 etc.
What is the equivalent in awk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In GNU awk that'd be:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
   str = "foo=23"
   val = gensub(/foo=([0-9]+)/,"\\1","",str)
   print "foo value is " val
}
$
$ gawk -f tst.awk
foo value is 23
```

In other awk's you'd need to use [g]sub() and/or match() and/or substr() depending on what else you do/don't want to match on. For example:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
   str = "foo=23"
   val = substr(str,match(str,/foo=[0-9]+/)+length("foo="))
   print "foo value is " val
}
$ awk -f tst.awk
foo value is 23
```

You'd need a third arg of ',RLENGTH-length("foo=")' on the substr() call if the target pattern isn't at the end of a line. Make "foo=" a variable if you like and if it itself can contain an RE there's a few more steps necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Also with GNU awk, use the [`match()` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions) and capture the parenthesis groups into an array.

```
str = "foo=23"
match(str, /foo=([0-9]+)/, ary)
print "foo value is " ary[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `sed`?

```
echo 'foo=23' | sed 's/foo=\([0-9]\+\)/foo value is \1/'
```

**EDIT:** If you really need to use `awk` you'll have to use `sub` or `gsub`. [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931034/awk-stumper-regex-substitution-within-a-field)

Comment: Thanks, I did not realise sed could do this.

Comment: Just be aware that "+" is an ERE meta-character, and many "sed"s by default only support BREs. For a solution portable to all seds you'd need to use [0-9][0-9]* instead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late for the party, but how about treating '=' as a field separator?  Worked a treat for me!

```
echo foo=23 | awk -F= '{ print $1 " value is " $2 }'
```